# LaTeX: Adding an Enumerate environment to a Tabular environment

Tags: latex

I am trying to add an ordered list (`enumerate`) to a table (`tabular`) in `LaTeX` with the following:

```
 \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
  \hline
  Event Flow & 
   \begin{enumerate}
   \item This is item 1
   \item This is item 2
   \end{enumerate}
  \\
  \hline
 \end{tabular}
```

But I am getting the following error:

> ! LaTeX Error: Something's
>   wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX
>   Companion for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...
>
> ```
>                                                l.34    \item T
>            his is item 1 ?
> ```

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

If I put the `enumerate` environment outside of the `tabular` environment it works, so I  guess I am currently missing something with my example of the table.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use p-columns in your table where you want the lists to be. In your example, since the list is in column 2, the following should work. Instead of:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
```

use

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|p{5cm}|}
```

This basically creates a paragraph environment inside that table cell, I think. See [this post](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1921) for more information.

Comment: Haven't tried it, but this was my first guess too.